# Detectin when Map<String> reach end

Tags: android, string, list, dictionary

i would like to execute a method when my Map list reach end. Here is my code:

```
    Map<String,?> keys = prefs.getAll();

    if (keys != null) {
        for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : keys.entrySet()){
            Log.d("allmyprefs", entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue().toString());
        }
        Log.d("allmyprefs", "the method to execut when the map reach end");
    }
```

I got all the keys and values reported fine in debug log but i wonder if there is a way to execute something else when the map list reach the last key. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just add it right after the for-loop

Comment: allright... this was quite stupid and i should think more before ask.. add as reply, i'll mark it as correct

Comment: no problem sometimes you just need an external perspective...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it right afer the for-loop
:)

Now you may or may not see Log statements out of sequence because the operation is not atomic within the system. (It waits for a buffer and a background thread flushes the log data out of the application context)

Comment: Hello. I'll still keep this solution as right but can you please edit it? if i add the method right before the loop the method is called before the loop start O.o. Do you know why?

Comment: I'm sorry!!! i wrote wrong! i was meaning i wrote the method right AFTER the loop! and it's executed before the loop start! look at my question! i updated with the actual code!

Comment: i get the log string ("the method to execut when the map reach end") before the values O.o

Comment: @iGio90 I think that Log.d and console don't behave sequentially

Answer (score 1):

To do that you would need to redefine your loop, probably with an Iterator like this:

```
Map<String,?> keys = prefs.getAll();
Iterator iter = keys.getIterator();

if (keys != null) {
  while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String,?> entry = iter.next();
    Log.d("allmyprefs", entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue().toString());

    if (!iter.hasNext()) {   // The Map is on the last item
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

**Edited**: Well, this supposing you want to do something with that item before quitting the loop, if not, the other user's answer is valid :)

Comment: Yes, i'll mark gtgaxiola answer as right since it does what i asked. Anyway a +1 on yours since it's also very usefull for my further usage! thanks for your method!